# Mapping behavior of imaginary axis via $v=\frac{z-a}{z+a}$

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, bilinear-form

I would like to know what the bilinear transform $v=\frac{z-a}{z+a}$ does to the imaginary axis, where $a$ is a real number.

I substituted $z=yi$ and calculated $|v|$ giving me $|v| =1$.
Is this enough proof to say that $v$ maps the imaginary axis to on the unit circle?

Comment: That depends on what else you know about fractional linear transforms (or Möbius transforms; not bilinear transforms).

Comment: What exactly is $a,$ out of curiosity?

Comment: @CameronBuie a real number

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you. I've an additional question though: My book states that the im-axis maps ''into'' the unit circle. What does that mean? –

Comment: That means that for every point $z$ on the imaginary axis, $\frac{z-a}{z+a}$ is a point of the unit circle.

Comment: @CameronBuie Okay, what then is the difference between ''onto'' and ''into'' or is there none?

Comment: In general, let's suppose that we have a function $f:X\to Y,$ with $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y.$ We say that $f$ maps $A$ *into* $B$ if $f(A)\subseteq B.$ We say that $f$ maps $A$ *onto* $B$ if $f(A)=B$.

Comment: Some texts say that $f$ maps $A$ *onto* $B$ if $f(A)\supseteq B,$ though, and say that $f$ maps $A$ *into and onto* $B$ if $f(A)=B$. It's something you'll have to check for yourself.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you. Am I correct to say that since the transformation is a bilinear (mapping lines to circles) we can say that the transform maps the im-axis ''onto'' in addition to that it maps ''(in)to'' the unit circle?

Comment: If you've seen that result before, then you can absolutely use it. Otherwise, you'll want to explicitly show it. Probably the simplest way is to find the inverse of the map and show that it maps the unit circle into the imaginary axis.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks a lot for your help. I've one last question: Can I also conclude that ''inside'' (here: |z|<1) and ''into'' the unit circle (|z|=1) are different?

Comment: Yes, they are different ideas. The first is "inside" in the sense of Jordan curves in the plane, meaning roughly that if $|z|<1,$ then the unit circle "forms a wall" between $z$ and the point at $\infty$, so $z$ is said to be inside the unit circle. The second is "inside" in a set-theoretic sense--every element in the set known as the imaginary axis is mapped to an element in the set known as the unit circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough to show that it maps the imaginary axis *to* the unit circle, but not quite enough to show that it maps the imaginary axis *onto* the unit circle. To draw that conclusion, we need to know that linear fractional transforms map circles to circles (in the Riemann sphere).

Alternately, you must *show* explicitly that it maps onto the unit circle (with one point deleted, if you don't count the "point at $\infty$" as being on the unit circle).